# How to construct a data structure dealing with closely interactive data

Tags: python, data-structures, pandas

well, I don't really know how to clearly name this kind of data.
Let's say I have a list of items, each item belongs to multiple categories, like

```
item 1 belongs to category A and B
item 2 belongs to category B and C
```

Therefore,

```
category A has item 1, 
category B has item 1 and item 2, 
category C has item 2.
```

Currently I construct two DataFrame (pandas) separately, category-based and item-based DataFrame, like

```
In[0]: import pandas as pd
In[1]: d = {'category': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'items': [1, [1,2], 2]}
In[2]: pd.DataFrame(data = d)

Out[2]:

  category   items
0        A       1
1        B  [1, 2]
2        C       2

In[3]: d = {'item': [1,2], 'category': [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C']]}
In[4]: pd.DataFrame(data = d)

Out[4]: 

  category  item
0   [A, B]     1
1   [B, C]     2
```

I want to have an efficient data structure to present the data relationship.
Use only one data structure instead of two to present these kind of data, any idea?

btw, my dataset have million of items and thousands of categories, efficiency is important for this data structure.

Comment: What kind of operations are you planning on doing on the data? A bipartite graph might be a useful representation.

Comment: @jme Since my dataset is over million rows, using graph is not practical. I need an efficient way to extract a list of categories that a certain item belongs to, or quick review what items are under this category.

Comment: Graphs with millions of nodes and edges aren't really impractical... It's just a question of whether it's the best representation for your task.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the columns as "belongs to" membership dummy variables, like this:

```
In [109]: pandas.DataFrame(
    [[1, 1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 1]], 
    columns=['itemName', 'belongsToA', 'belongsToB', 'belongsToC']
)

Out[109]: 
   itemName  belongsToA  belongsToB  belongsToC
0         1           1           1           0
1         2           0           1           1
```

but really it depends entirely on what algorithms and operations you plan to use with the data.

Comment: I think this might take too much memory space for me, since my dataset has millions of items, thousand of categories. That data structure might be too large.

Comment: but this is a great idea, I never thought about it. I am already trying to implement it, still waiting for other possible method.

Comment: At that level, it is not reasonable to try manipulating the data in memory in pandas. You need either a streaming data service so that the data is loaded and processed in chunks (serially or in parallel) or else you should just bite the bullet and use one of the many database technologies that can directly handle data of that scale, such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, Vertica, Cassandra, or many other things. Don't try to jam the problem into Python just because it feels easier, or because pandas has convenience functions you like. Learn to make then work in an appropriate database environment.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably over-thinking the problem. Very often the simple solution is the answer. It's usually a good idea to at least *try* the simple solution, because if it does solve the problem you're done quickly. And if it doesn't work, you've learned more about the nature of your data.

You have items and categories. An item can belong to multiple categories, and a category can have multiple items. The naive way to do this is of course to keep everything in an array and sequentially search it. That would *work*, but would be terribly slow.

The next way would be to keep two separate data structures: one for Items and one for Categories. The Items data structure is a hash map indexed by the item ID. Each item holds a list of category identifiers for the categories that the item belongs to.

The Categories is a hash map that is indexed by category ID. Each Category entry holds a list of the items that belong to that category.

The memory requirement for the items list is proportional to the number of items times the average number of categories that an item belongs to. But remember that the categories list in each item is just a list of identifiers. Or perhaps references. So if you have a million items that, on average, belong to three categories each, then you need storage for the million items plus three million references.

The categories list memory requirement is proportional to the number of categories times the average number of items per category. Again, the item references will be small.

This might require a bit more memory than keeping everything in a single data structure, but lookups and insertions are fast. Deletions are somewhat slower, but it's not terrible. Lookup, in particular, is O(1) for either a category or an item.

The *worst case* memory requirements, of course, are horrible (i.e 2*Items*Columns), but that's only going to happen if every item belongs to an absurd number of categories.

If you really need it to be a single data structure, wrap the two hash maps into a single data structure that you can query by item or by category.

Were I in your position, I'd give the above a shot. As I said, it's easy to implement and might very well do what you want. I'm not a Python programmer, so I can't really give you an example.

Comment: Thanks, you two's solutions do help. I am sorry that I cannot vote up for both of yours answer since my reputation here haven't met the criteria.